# Language and region enumeration

Tags: c++, enums, locale, std, standard-library

In my company we deal with different locale options in our libraries. We take string parameters for locale settings. However, I prefer enums over strings since they are type safe and doesn't need string validations.

Is there an enumeration in standard library for language and regions? If not is there a plan to include a thing like this?

Creating a common library and defining a custom enum is not possible because of the compilation issues of static libraries on iOS. (Duplicate symbols.)

Comment: `Is there an enumeration in standard library for language and regions?` No there is not. The string form for locale names is not standardized either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not as of C++14, and I’m unfamiliar with plans to add one.  Creating an exhaustive enumeration of region codes gets into all kinds of unpleasant political issues, like [whether or not the Falkland Islands should be separate from the UK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falkland_Islands_sovereignty_dispute), and most standards committees are hesitant to take official stances.

Comment: Hmm... Why is there so much change? I thought ISO was about standardization, not changing things around...

Comment: @qqww2: I misspoke when I wrote ‘ISO language and region codes change _constantly_’. [CLDR](http://cldr.unicode.org/) data changes constantly, but I’m not sure about the codes themselves. I’ve edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Right, political issues might be a problem. Also, when I look at the list of values in that page I see it would be impractical to make that an enum.